# Recomposed matrix from Decomposed matrix doesn't match

Tags: opengl-es, xna, directx

This is a Matrix knowledge question,  I am talking about XNA but only as a reference

I decomposed a matrix on XNA and got the decomposed values, then just tried to create again
the Matrix from those values and the resultant Matrix does not match the original one

I tried to Normalize the quaternion

I tried to generate a Rotation Matrix from the Quaternion

I tried swaping the order of the Transformation   SRT ,  STR,  TRS, TSR,  RST, RTS

Why I am doing this?   I am creating my own model importer and I am comparing my results
with XNA using the same model,  so I am reading almost (some decimal difference) the same source  SRT as the XNA's decomposed values, but my resultant Matrix didn't match XNA, so I went back to the basics and tried to decompose/recompose the XNA Matrix but I found it doesn't match either

These are the Original XNA Matrix values

```
?this.XNAModel.Bones[0].Transform
{{M11:1.331581E-06 M12:-5.551115E-17 M13:1 M14:0} 
{M21:1 M22:-4.16881E-11 M23:-1.331581E-06 M24:0} 
{M31:4.16881E-11 M32:1 M33:8.15331E-23 M34:0}
{M41:0.03756338 M42:37.46099 M43:2.230549 M44:1} }
```

Decomposition , lFlag is true

```
bool lFlag = this.XNAModel.Bones[0].Transform.Decompose(out lDecScale, out lDecRotation, out lDecTranslation);

//decomposed values
?lDecScale
{X:1 Y:1 Z:1}

?lDecRotation    //quat
{X:-0.5000003 Y:-0.4999996 Z:-0.4999996 W:0.5000004}

?lDecTranslation
{X:0.03756338 Y:37.46099 Z:2.230549}
```

Recompose the matrix from the decomposed values , I've tried all the combinations SRT

```
//lDecRotation.Normalize();

Matrix lRecompose = Matrix.CreateScale(lDecScale) * 
Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(lDecRotation) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(lDecTranslation);
```

Quaternion not normalized result  using  SRT  , doesnt' match original Matrix

```
?lRecompose
{{M11:1.430511E-06 M12:-5.960464E-08 M13:0.9999999 M14:0}
{M21:0.9999999 M22:1.192093E-07 M23:-1.370907E-06 M24:0}
{M31:-5.960464E-08 M32:0.9999999 M33:1.192093E-07 M34:0}
{M41:0.03756338 M42:37.46099 M43:2.230549 M44:1} }
```

Quaternion normalized result using SRT, doesnt' match original Matrix

```
?lRecompose
{{M11:1.192093E-06 M12:-5.960464E-08 M13:1 M14:0}
{M21:1 M22:-1.192093E-07 M23:-1.370907E-06 M24:0}
{M31:-5.960464E-08 M32:1 M33:-1.192093E-07 M34:0}
{M41:0.03756338 M42:37.46099 M43:2.230549 M44:1} }
```

This is what my model importer read

```
?this.ModelNew.Bones[0].Scale 
{X:1 Y:1 Z:1}

?this.ModelNew.Bones[0].Rotation 
{X:-0.0002303041 Y:-8.604798E-05 Z:-5.438289}
```

There is a small diference between this result and the Decomposed one from XNA

```
//My importer, based on the above Rotation Vector,  converted to radians 
?lQuat    {X:-0.4999999 Y:-0.5 Z:-0.5 W:0.4999999}
//XNA  
{X:-0.5000003 Y:-0.4999996 Z:-0.4999996 W:0.5000004}

?this.ModelNew.Bones[0 ].Translation
{X:0.03756338 Y:37.46099 Z:2.230549}
```

Comment: What does OpenGL have to do with this? In fact, what does *Unity3d* have to do with this? You're using XNA, which uses D3D.

Comment: Well,  what I am asking is no XNA specific,  its more about Matrix knowledge (what I am lacking).  So I am tagging in that way to reach all the people who potentially know the answer.  I may get the same problem using other tool. Summary,  this is a call for everybody who uses Matrices and game programming related stuff.

Comment: By the way Nicol,  you may know the answer, could you please take a look at the full post?

Comment: Inspect those values closely, most of them are almost the same. Most of this can be attributed to floating point rounding.

Comment: Hi Scott,  the values on M4x  are the same, they correspond to the Transalation, but the other Matrix Rows are wrong,  I m sure is becuase the rotation value,  but why decomposing and then recomposing give a wrong result,  unless the decompose function is wrong

Comment: To whom it may concerns:  I got edited twice my post and got removed the opengl tag.  OK , I understand that people think XNA is for rookies , some people dont like DirectX, and some others love OpenGL because is Open,  well for me all them are for the same purpose,  I was doing XNA , now I am porting to OpenGL-ES,   they both are a vehicule to acomplish my purposes. So , please read the full post, and dont stop reading until you get the first "XNA" word.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your graphics API manages matrices, and how your modelling software exports them, you may have to transpose the matrix before decomposing it, and then transpose the result after recomposing it to get the same result as the original matrix.

By the way, the correct order for recomposing is to translate first, then rotate, then scale.